# How to rescue data after malformed chunk in a byte stream which is written with writeDelimitedTo()

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I use protobuf-java-util:3.0.0-beta-2.

I create a file which contains a lot of Protobuf messages which are written with `Message#writeDelimitedTo()`. The code is something like this:

```
Iterable<SomeMessage> messages = getHugeDataSet();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("a_lot_of_messages.protobuf");
for (SomeMessage msg : messages) msg.writeDelimitedTo(os);
```

And I read those files with `Builder#mergeDelimitedFrom()`. Something like this:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("a_lot_of_messages.protobuf");
SomeMessage msg1 = SomeMessage.newBuilder().mergeDelimitedFrom(is).build();
SomeMessage msg2 = SomeMessage.newBuilder().mergeDelimitedFrom(is).build();
... // This is simplified - it's implemented as an Iterator in the real code
```

With that way, I can read the vast majority of files without any problems but I sometimes get exceptions like this:

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message had invalid UTF-8. ...
```

The code which writes those files run on mobile devices which get power failure sometimes. In such cases, **my app keeps writing to the same file** and  chances of getting that exceptions are high. So, apparently my code creates some malformed files on such occasions. My code can read some parts of the file, but it can't read the parts after the malformed chunk due to the error.

Now I need to rescue and read the data after the malformed chunk, but I couldn't find any way to do that. So, I'd like to know the following:

1. Is there any way to rescue and read the parts which are written by the code above after the malformed chunk?
2. If there is no way to do that, how can I improve my code so my app can cope with such problems? Is there any best practice which is power failure tolerant?

Full exception stacktrace is something like this:

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message had invalid UTF-8.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidUtf8(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:120) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readStringRequireUtf8(CodedInputStream.java:410) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.example.Model$SomeData.<init>(Model.java:14775) ~[my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.example.Model$SomeData.<init>(Model.java:14717) ~[my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.example.Model$SomeData$1.parsePartialFrom(Model.java:18240) ~[my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.example.Model$SomeData$1.parsePartialFrom(Model.java:18234) ~[my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:495) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.example.Model$SomeMessage.<init>(Model.java:27250) ~[my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.example.Model$SomeMessage.<init>(Model.java:27197) ~[my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.example.Model$SomeMessage$1.parsePartialFrom(Model.java:28678) ~[my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.example.Model$SomeMessage$1.parsePartialFrom(Model.java:28672) ~[my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.example.Model$SomeMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(Model.java:27802) ~[my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.example.Model$SomeMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(Model.java:27653) ~[my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:235) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:516) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:290) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:305) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(AbstractMessage.java:530) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:311) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(AbstractMessage.java:522) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.example.MyUtils.read(MyUtils.java:54) [my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite problematic to recover message boundaries from raw protobuf data. This in general applies to data formats, the smaller and more compressed it is, the less resilient it is to transmission errors.

The best way would be if there is some byte sequence that always occurs in the beginning of a message. For example, if you happen to have any nearly-constant fields like `required string software_version = 1;`, you could search for that in the binary data and so find the starting point of the next message.

If that is not the case, you can introduce such a marker when writing your message. For example, pick some 64 bit random number as your marker. Either you can write it separately to the file outside protobuf, or you can have a `fixed64` field with index 1 in your message to get it near the beginning.

Even though the marker might occur elsewhere in your data randomly, that shouldn't cause too large problems as you can just skip messages that do not parse.

Comment: Agreed. I'm thinking of introducing such a marker as you suggested, plus some escape sequence like explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8541805/3591946 to prevent unintentional skipping or parse errors. Another option which comes to my mind is that truncating garbage bytes before start writing after a power failure, it may take some time to parse the file from the beginning though.